# How can I specify Appium path?

Tags: automated-tests, appium

I Can't uninstall my Appium by using npm

`npm uninstall -g appium`

or update by

`npm install -g appium@1.19.1`

Those commands still make the same result, That my Appium still be the old version.

**How can I specify, Which path that my Appium has been installed ?**

**How I can update it ?**

Answer (score 0):

This is not Appium question, but node/npm one

`npm root -g` will show you the path to globally installed modules:

`npm rm -g appium` should delete the package completely

you may also what to clear cache `npm cache clear`

Comment: I already found the root cause, It about my path in system env. But your answer helps me for investigation. Thank.